# Help me identify this font please

Tags: font-identification, font-design

Can anyone help me with this? I have to redesign a logo, and need to know what font this one is. I already tried whaththefont and all those apps.

The slanted 'e's are very characteristic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a pixelated font or the image you have provided is actually low resolution and pixelated?

Comment: I think the quality of the image is too low to easily identify it using one of those online font ID apps. Have you nothing better quality? If not. you may just have to search through lists of serif fonts.

Comment: Thanks guys. I already have updated another version of the mark/type so you can try to figure out what the font is this nightmare. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

It looks very much like [Benguiat](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/benguiat/pro-book/) to me. The high crossbar on the **H** and the angled bar on the **e** are quite distinctive.

[image: H O T E L São João de Deus rendered in ITC Benguiat Pro Book]

Comment: Absolutely right @r3mainer. A few hours of searching and trying and I finally made it. I've already found it before seeing your comment but thanks a lot for your time. Amazing effort. Keep safe mate.

Comment: @nelsoncosta you should mark this as accepted answer